# Deploy docker private image to compute engine instance by using GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci

```
stages:
  - build
  - docker-push
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

build:
  stage: build
  image: node:latest
  script:
    - yarn install
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/

docker:
  stage: docker-push
  image: docker:18.09.7

  services:
    - docker:18.09.7-dind

  script:
    - docker login --username=$DOCKER_USERNAME --password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD
    - docker tag $DOCKER_REPOSITORY:$CI_RUNNER_ID $DOCKER_REPOSITORY:latest
    - docker push $DOCKER_REPOSITORY

test:
  stage: deploy
  image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
  script:
    - echo $GCP_ACCESS_JSON > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account $GCP_CE_PROJECT_EMAIL --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
```

I have this `.gitlab-ci.yml` file . I've successfully created docker image and published it to docker hub private repository . I also have created `GCP` compute enigne instance and as you can see in gitlab-ci file I can login to this instance by using `gcloud` command , now I want to find some `gcloud` command which will give an opportunity to deploy this private docker hub image to this compute engine instance . How can i do it ? If you need more information , pls let me know !

Answer (score 3):

If you are not tied to docker hub and can instead use the [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/), there is a [simple gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#deploying_a_container_on_a_new_vm_instance) to deploy an instance using a [very slimmed down operating system](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits) that is designed only for containers:

```
 gcloud compute instances create-with-container [INSTANCE_NAME] \
     --container-image [DOCKER_IMAGE]
```

However, it does not support private docker hub registries except for GCR.  [Here is a guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) to pushing to GCR if that is a route you can take.

Otherwise, there isn't really a gcloud command to do what you want, other than by perhaps configuring a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) or [cloud-init](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#using_cloud-init) file that has the necessary data to authenticate and pull from the private repository, but it certainly is not automated.

Answer (score 2):

Compute Engine VM instance by itself does not run container images.

1) Install Docker and deploy the image manually.

2) Deploy Compute Engine with Container OS and deploy your image manually.

3) Switch to Google Container Registry and deploy the image with your GCE VM instance running Container OS.

Comment: Manual deploying isn't the case for me , because I want to do it automatically by using .gitlab-ci.yml file , thanks for your advice, I will try to find out the third case which you have described .

Comment: You will not be able to use your manifest with Google Cloud tools, but you can locally on your desktop or a VM. You can build your images with Docker, push to Container Registry, but Google does not support your manifest directly. You will need to adapt your methods to fit the Google Cloud tools (Container Registry, Cloud Build, Container OS).

Answer (score 0):

gcloud create instance make sure docker available(if not install)
Deploy manually container stream to gcloud
or gcloud instance to connect dockerhub registry and pull your .yml file deploy it